# Get index or use pair list in mysql?

Tags: .net, mysql, dapper

I want to do something like the below where ls is a pair (id and value to match blah). Maybe if i could get the index of the list match I can just use the list normally and grab the id in code

```
select @id from table1 where blah in @ls
```

Comment: So unclear.   What is grab id in code?

Comment: @Blam `@var` is a variable i passed in through params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper is a very thin veneer over SQL. The *only* thing it adds as a syntax change is `IN` expansion from:

```
x in @foo
```

to

```
x in (@foo0, @foo1, @foo2, @foo3)
```

However, I don't think your query can be written like that. The first step, then, is to write your query in regular SQL. If this was SQL-Server, I would be thinking:

- a UDF that turns a delimited string input into a tabular output
- an inner join

for example:

```
select #x.id
from dbo.MyMagicUdf(@s) #x -- has columns id and value
inner join table1 t on t.blah = #x.value -- or whatever the join is
```

But to repeat: the first step is to write it in SQL for your RDBMS. Once you have *that* working, it should be a breeze to get dapper to work with it.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to write it in regular SQL however i figured out a different way to write it. It requires subqueries and CONCAT